# Deploy Artefact at nexus Server - error dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, jar, nexus

I have setup a nexus server and afterwards I had the opinion to simple deploy an artefact to this nexus server. Therefore I created a simple Java project with this pom:

```
<project xmlns="...">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My settings file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings ...>
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>     
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://it-nexus.domain:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
     <id>nexus</id>
     <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Then I have tried to deploy my artefact with:

> mvn deploy

and I got this Error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
:jar:2.6 in http://it-nexus.domain:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Actually I don't know what I am doing wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong (well, everything really).

First, you can remove `profiles` and everything under it, along with `activeProfiles`, from your server.xml file. Next, you need to add a `servers` entry, containing a server with the `id`, 'nexus' (assuming you're uploading to the same nexus instance you're using to mirror central), along with a username and password of some sort.

Then you have to have a `distributionManagement` section in your pom, referencing the same `server` you've specified in the settings.xml file, and configure the maven-deploy plugin. Documentation for that can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html). You will also need an `scm` section.

The actual error you talk about is probably because your nexus server isn't actually configured to proxy/mirror `central`. Oh, and you should use `*` as the argument to `mirrorOf`.